# discord.py - Unloading Cogs with async cleanup function

Tags: discord.py

I'm running discord.py 1.6.
I have a Cog loaded which maintains a dashboard-style message (periodically updating) on Discord.

When unloading this Cog, I want to automatically delete this dashboard message using the default
`await message.delete()`
approach, which is an async call.

According to the docs, there are basically 2 options to auto-run Cog-cleanup code:

1. Extension cleanup function `teardown()` - NOT async.
   https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/extensions.html#cleaning-up
2. Cog method `cog_unload()` - NOT async either.
   https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_unload

When loading a Cog, however, there are `async` pre- and post-invoke hooks available.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_before_invoke

Hence, my question is:
Is there any way, to automatically run (`await`) async code, when **unloading** Cogs?

EDIT:
Solved it by building a custom extension reloader, calling exit(), reload() and init().

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [asyncio.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) ? It is usually the solution when trying to call an `async` function in a synchronous thread since you do not need to `await` the run() function

Comment: turned out it doesn't execute the cleanup function at all.
also tried `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.exit())` but didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

[asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) schedules the coroutine to be run, but doesn't wait for it to run. If you're using Python 3.6 or lower, use [asyncio.ensure_future()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future).